# Laravel | Run IF every page

Tags: php, laravel, function

I want to run the following code to check if the user is logged via social media and if so redirect him to the edit profile page, so he's obligated to update his information, I don't want the user logged via social media to be able to navigate my website without having their Name, username and profile resume set.

```
public function check_user_info()
{
    $user = User::where('access_token', Auth::user()->access_token)->first();

    if (empty($user->fname) || empty($user->lname) || is_null($user->username) || empty($user->username))
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('modify')->with([
            'user' => $user,
            ]);
    }
    return view('home');
}
```

Comment: You can use `middleware` for that. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware

Comment: I just created a middleware, added it in the kernel.php but nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a user policy and add the following function :

```
public function home(User $user)
{
    return (empty($user->fname) || empty($user->lname) || is_null($user->username) || empty($user->username));
}
```

and in you home controller :

```
public function index(){
    try{
        $this->authorize('home', User::class);
    }catch(AuthorizationException $e){
        return view('modify')->with([
        'user' => Auth::user(),
        ]);
    }
     return view('home');
}
```